# ConcurrentModificationException on LinkedList

Tags: java

The code given below dont throw a ConcurrentModificationException.But if i add 2 more elements into the LinkedList, it throws the Exception. Why ?

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");

for (String s : list) {
    if (s.equals("B")) {
        list.remove(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/4290096

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a list, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Comment: I guess which question was asked more times, this or strings comparison..

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove items from a Collection while iterating over it using an enhanced `for` loop. What you want to do instead is this:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String s = iterator.next();
  if (s.equals("B")) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know Iterator is good for such operations, but i m curious to know why only the last and 2nd last elements are removed from the linkedList without throwing the ConcurrentModificationException ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove an entry from a list in a for loop, you have to use an iterator, like that:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  String entry = iterator.next();
  if(entry.equals("B") {
   iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that's uncanny. :P

Comment: @RedRoboHood what do you mean? =)

Comment: @RedRoboHood You were a couple secs faster=) This moment, when being second costs you at least 10 points of rep, lol.

Comment: Yeah... that's just how SO is, I guess. Not sure why your post got downvoted, though.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Hey cool, I also got downvoted. Whats wrong with those guys? They thought I just copy pasted your answer, did they? :P

Comment: That kind of sucks. Here, have some rep anyways. :)

Comment: B could be removed in a foreach loop also without any exception. What i want to know is why it throws ConcurrentModificationException when i add 2 more elements into the list ? like -
                list.add("A");
  list.add("B");
  list.add("C");
  list.add("D");

Comment: @Bibhudutta please do some effort and see at least [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)